# Setting global variable in Express and rendering the same using Handlebars

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm trying to use (in my handlebars) the logged in user data that I have globally set in app.js.

The following is my code :

**app.js**

```
// Set global variable
app.use(function (req, res, next) {    
    res.locals.user = req.user || null    
    next()
})
```

**index.hbs**

> The index.hbs will render the posts of the user, for each posts, it
> will render post_title as {{title}} , post body as {{body}}. These are
> all working fine, but what I want here is an edit icon above the posts
> of only the user who is logged in. So if there's total six posts on
> the page, and only two of them are by the logged in user, the update
> icon must show above those two posts and the rest of the posts should
> be shown without the update icon. So here, the updateIcon function
> will be called with the *user* (which is the user_id against the
> post), *../user* (which is the logged in user one level up, at the
> global level), and the *_id* which is the post id.

```
<h1>All posts</h1>
<div class="row">    
    {{#each posts}}        
        <div class="col s12 m4">
            <div class="card">                      
                <div class="card-image">           
                    {{{updateIcon user ../user _id}}}
                </div>
                <div class="card-content center-align">
                    <h5>{{title}}</h5>
                    <p>{{body)}}</p>
                    <br>
                    <div class="chip">
                        <img src="{{user.image}}" alt="">
                        <a href="/stories/user/{{user._id}}">{{user.displayName}}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action center-align">
                    <a href="/stories/{{_id}}" class="btn grey">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <p>No posts</p>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

**hbs.js**

> This is the javascript file where I have written the updateIcon
> function. It receives the arguments from the handlebars template
> function call, along with an additional parameter *floating* set to
> `true`.

```
updateIcon: function (postUser, loggedInUser, postId, floating = true) {
      console.log(`${postUser._id} ${loggedInUser._id}`)
        if (postUser._id.toString() === loggedInUser._id.toString()) {        
          if (floating) {
            return `<a href="/posts/update/${postId}" class="btn-floating halfway-fab blue"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-small"></i></a>`
          } else {
            return `<a href="/posts/update/${postId}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>`
          }
        } else {
          return ''
        }
      },
```

> When I run my application and click to check all posts from the menu I
> get the following error :

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') at Object.updateIcon (/media/jdpc/HDD1/myPortfolioProjects/pick-a-pen/helpers/hbs.js:25:50)`

Comment: If `loggedInUser` is `null` then you cannot very well call `loggedInUser._id`. You need to add some null checks to your condition, like `if (postUser && loggedInUser && postUser._id.toString() === loggedInUser._id.toString()) {`

Comment: Fixed !! Changed `if (postUser._id.toString() === loggedInUser._id.toString())` to `if (storyUser._id.toString() === loggedUser.id)` in updateIcon helper